# Does Windows 10 energy saver conflict with Itunes running?

Tags: windows-10, itunes

my computer works fine until I leave it alone.  If I am playing Itunes, after about 30 minutes it begins to stop for 5-10 seconds, play 5 seconds or so and then stop and restart.  When I get to the computer, it is frozen and spins for about 10 minutes before becoming responsive.

It is this a conflict between the computer wanting to sleep while Itunes is on?  If so, what can be done about it?  Thanks...

Comment: When you play, is there an Apple device connected or not?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this.  No Apple device connected.  Just a Toshiba laptop L655 64 bit machine.  I have an Ipad but it is sleeping. I changed my sleep computer setting to 4 hours...so that is not the problem.  Itunes on/off and Windows 10 intermittently freezing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It could be iTunes or not. After 30 minutes are there any specific events scheduled to happen? Perhaps enter into sleep mode? Reproduce the issue, track the time and shutdown iTunes when computer responds. Now, I want you to click start > type eventvwr.msc and press enter and open up the Event Viewer. Expand event logs and view the Administrative Log, System Log and Application Log. See if you can find a trace. This will help us to determine the issue.

Comment: critical errors

Comment: critical errors    Critical 5/14/2016 2:31:06 PM Kernel-Power 142 (173);    Errors:  Error (499) samples:  5/14/2016 3:13:43 PM Service Control Manager 7003 None;  Error 5/14/2016 3:09:17 PM Apps 2484 (2400);  Error 5/14/2016 3:03:56 PM Application Error 1000 (100),  Warnings: 126 in last hour.  Sample: Warning 5/14/2016 3:14:49 PM disk 153 None        Does this help?

Comment: the best I can do other than the above is to unistall/install programs...let me know and thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an application hang (2484). However it looks like an app but might not. 1000. Again a similar issue. You have to expand the errors to see the idea. Or else perhaps you can upload the log after exporting it and share the link. This Kernel power issue is due tot unexpected shutdown. You can ignore it.